# iPhone UIImagePicker issue

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, modalviewcontroller

I've an issue with the UIImagePicker.

When I first display it I get a white bar about the size of the status bar appearing above the controls. Though on the second time it then doesn't show up but reappears on the third time and in that pattern.

It looks like this:

[image]

But If I zoom in it appears normal:

[image]

I hide the Tab Bar and navigation bar when the picker is displayed (modally) if I don't these overlay the picker. I then unhide them after.

I don't understand how it displays the white space then doesn't and then does again.

Have anyone had this issue?

Thanks

EDIT- If I set [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO animated:NO]; after presenting the modalview the issue is gone.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing:

```
myImagePickerController.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
```